# How to block specific pc's in squid proxy

Tags: proxy, squid

I want to block Specific PCs like Windows and Macintosh using the ACLs in the squid proxy.

Below is the sample log of the squid proxy

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_4; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.18.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Safari/533.18.5

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:35.0) Geck /20100101 Firefox/35.0

I can block the browsers uisng ACLs in Squid proxy.
But i need to block PCs also so Is there any way to accomplish this using ACLs in squid Proxy.

Answer (score 1):

You can block the MAC Address of the PC's to block their access.
For example MAC address of their PC is: C0-18-85-C1-46-87
Then just add:-

```
acl banned arp C0:18:85:C1:46:87
```

```
http_access deny banned
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using authentication make a file in /etc/squid folder say - "banned.txt"
make new acl called banned_users-

> acl banned_users src -i /etc/squid/banned.txt

now in ACL's use-

> http_access deny banned_users

it blocks user's authentication of that user on any IP and any MAC address